# If $X^*$ is reflexive then so is $X.$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, reflexive-space

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space. Then there is a linear isometry $J_X : X \longrightarrow X^{**}$ such that $J_X(x) (\varphi) = \varphi (x), x \in X, \varphi \in X^*.$ Then $X$ is said to be reflexive if $J_X (X) = X^{**}$ i.e. if $J_X$ is onto.
>
> Prove that $X$ is reflexive if so is $X^*.$

**Attempt** $:$ Let $\psi \in X^{***}$ be such that $\psi (J_X(x)) = 0,$ for all $x \in X.$ Since $X^*$ is reflexive there exists $\varphi \in X^*$ such that $J_{X^*} (\varphi) = \psi.$ So $0 = \psi (J_X(x)) = J_{X^*} (\varphi) (J_X(x)) = J_X(x) (\varphi) = \varphi (x),$ for all $x \in X.$ Hence $\varphi = 0$ in $X^*.$ Therefore $\psi = J_{X^*} (\varphi) = J_{X^*} (0) = 0$ in $X^{***}.$ So any bounded linear functional on $X^{**}$ which vanishes on $J_X (X)$ is identically zero. So if $\overline {J_X (X)} \subsetneq X^{**}$ then by Hahn-Banach theorem there would exist a $y \in X^{**} \setminus {J_X(X)}$ (so that $\text {dist}\ (y, J_X(X)) \gt 0)$ and a $T \in X^{***}$ such that $T(y) = 1$ and $T(x) = 0,$ for every $x \in J_X (X),$ which will lead us to a contradiction. What will happen if $\overline {J_X(X)} = X^{**}$ i.e. if $J_X (X)$ is dense in $X^{**}\ $?

Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Or $X^*\cong Y^*\implies X^{**}\cong Y^{**}\implies X\cong Y$, then take $Y=X^{**}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is not true without completeness of $X$. Take $X=\ell_0$ the space of all sequences which are eventually $0$ with the $\ell^{2}$ norm. The dual of this space is the usual $\ell^{2}$ space which is reflexive. But $X$ itself is not reflexive since any reflexive space is necessarily complete.

Of course, if $X$ is complete then you don't run into a problem with your proof.

Comment: @Phibetakappa If $X$ is complete then so is $J_X(X)$ since $J_X$ is an isometry. Hence $J_X(X)$ is closed in this case.

Comment: Oh! I get it now.

Comment: How do I prove that $(\ell_0)^* = \ell_2\ $?

Comment: The dual of any normed linear space is the same as the dual of its completion. because any continuous linear functional extends uniquely to the completion preserving the norm @Phibetakappa

Comment: I think I should proceed as follows $:$ For any element $x = (x_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \ell^2$ the map $\varphi_x : \ell_0 \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ defined by $\varphi_x (y) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n y_n$ is a bounded linear map with $\|\varphi\| = \|x\|_2,$ where $y = (y_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \ell_0.$ Am I right sir?